# MVC3 Razor View Multi Select Dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-select

I want to create a multiselect dropdown (all options having checkbox to select) in MVC3 razor view (cshtml).

I have searched it a lot and everywhere I found recommendations to use Jquery plugins like chozen etc. Due to some constraints, I cannot use external tools.

Comment: May  below link will help you:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776851/how-to-use-multiple-select-in-mvc-4][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776851/how-to-use-multiple-select-in-mvc-4

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use external tools, the only way is to use `ListBox` helper. Your code could look like below:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Selected, 
        Model.AllItems.Select(fl => new SelectListItem {
             Text = fl.Name,
             Value = fl.Id.ToString(),
             Selected = Model.Selected.Any(y => y.Id == fl.Id)
   }), new {Multiple = "multiple"})
```

It will render classic HTML listbox.

BTW Choosen is just Javascript plugin which will won't modify anything in your code. It will just replace in user browser "GUI" to select items.